# Custom widget defined in an HTML page loaded as dojox.layout.contentpane using href and inserted as tab page not parsing custom widgets

Tags: javascript, dojo

I was trying to add a new tab page using `tab.addchild` programmatically after creating `dojox.layout.contentpane` with `href` attribute.

Following is the sample snippet of the relevant code (`tabMain` is tab control placed in the page)

```
  dijit.byId('tabMain').addChild(new dojox.layout.ContentPane({
     title: 'My page',
     href: 'country.jsp',
     closable: true,
     parseOnLoad: true,
     postCreate: function () {
         dojo.parser.parse();
     }));
```

This `country.jsp` has custom widget (that contain two standard dijit widgets).
But the custom widgets are not parsed  and hence I am not getting the custom widget properly loaded, where as other standard dijits mentioned in the `country.jsp` loads perfectly.

To rule out the problem with my page and custom widget declarations,  I put this custom widget directly in a page without loading inside a contentpane/tab (and loaded inside as dialog page), it works fine.  So, I assume that the dojo parser is not parsing the custom widget, when I load it in the content pane as shown in the above code.

Does this mean, custom widget cannot be used for such type of loading or Am I missing anything extra to force the parser to work?  I tried running parser on load, downloadend, downloadstart, ready events, but with no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing anything about DOJO, your provided snippet is missing a closing bracket inside the `ContentPane` constructor call, making it invalid (and thus not parsable).

Try:

```
dijit.byId('tabMain').addChild(new dojox.layout.ContentPane({
    title: 'My page',
    href: 'country.jsp',
    closable: true,
    parseOnLoad: true,
    postCreate: function () {
        dojo.parser.parse();
    }
}));
```

Comment: That is typing error, when I copied the code. In fact, I have not copied the full code, but just a part relevant to my question only. The bracket was indeed there...So, the question yet to be answered